# Erro ao criar Trigger com mais de uma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Estou tendo problemas ao criar uma Trigger que modifica mais de uma tabela.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS vendedor_pago;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER vendedor_pago AFTER UPDATE ON parcelas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE vendas, comissao, parcelas
        SET vendas.`conf_pagamento` = 1,
        comissao.`pago` = IF(parcelas.`parcelas_pagas` = parcelas.`num_parcelas`, 1, 0) 
    WHERE parcelas.`id_venda` = comissao.`id_venda`
        AND comissao.`id_venda` = vendas.OLD.`id`
        AND vendas.`id` = parcelas.`id_venda`
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Inclusive não sei se a forma `vendas.OLD.id` está correta. O seguinte erro é retornado ao executar:

> 1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'END' na linha
>   10

Também gostaria de saber se o loop FOR EACH é realmente necessário, tendo em vista que desejo alterar somente um registro de cada tabela.

Comment: Você esqueceu o `BEGIN` e `END`

Comment: Ainda assim deu erro. Atualizei a pergunta com o resultado.

Comment: Falta também `FOR EACH ROW` após o nome da tabela. Dá uma olhada nos [exemplos documentados](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Isso é mesmo necessário quando quero atualizar apenas 1 registro na tabela? Atualizando a pergunta novamente.. Dá uma olhada

Answer (score 0):

A Trigger que resolveu o problema, embora para mim pareça estranho um *OLD* ser usado sozinho quando há 3 tabelas no escopo do *UPDATE*:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS vendedor_pago;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER vendedor_pago AFTER UPDATE ON parcelas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE vendas, comissao, parcelas
        SET vendas.`conf_pagamento` = 1,
        comissao.`pago` = IF(parcelas.`parcelas_pagas` = parcelas.`num_parcelas`, 1, 0) 
    WHERE parcelas.`id_venda` = comissao.`id_venda`
        AND comissao.`id_venda` = OLD.`id`
        AND vendas.`id` = parcelas.`id_venda`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```